# How to generate a JSON field based on results of a Kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Say we have a table like this:

```
datatable(one:string, two:string)
[
    "A",  "textA",
    "A",  "textB",
    "A",  "textC",
    "B",  "textA1",
    "B",  "textB1",
    "B",  "textC1",
]
| summarize by one
```

We need to get alongside the *one* summary a JSON column with all the instances of *two* summarized. In this case, we would get:

```
A, "textA,textB,textC"
B, "textA1,textB1,textC1"
```

I know how to pack fields of one column into a new one but I have no idea about how to gather the results from different rows summarized into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[make_list()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction)

```
datatable(one:string, two:string)
[
    "A",  "textA",
    "A",  "textB",
    "A",  "textC",
    "B",  "textA1",
    "B",  "textB1",
    "B",  "textC1",
]
| summarize make_list(two) by one
```

| one | list_two |
| --- | --- |
| A | ["textA","textB","textC"] |
| B | ["textA1","textB1","textC1"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjfy8VKvikqLMvHQdhZLyfChbk5crmpdLAQiUHJV0gGRJakUJkIUh5oRFzBku5oTQa4hF0AmboDNYMJaXq0ahuDQ3N7EosypVITcxOzU%20J7O4RAPoRk2FpEoFoLsBtRoWcMUAAAA=)

Add [strcat_array()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcat-arrayfunction) if you want to convert the result to a string.

```
datatable(one:string, two:string)
[
    "A",  "textA",
    "A",  "textB",
    "A",  "textC",
    "B",  "textA1",
    "B",  "textB1",
    "B",  "textC1",
]
| summarize strcat_array(make_list(two), ",") by one
```

| one | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | textA,textB,textC |
| B | textA1,textB1,textC1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjfy8VKvikqLMvHQdhZLyfChbk5crmpdLAQiUHJV0gGRJakUJkIUh5oRFzBku5oTQa4hF0AmboDNYMJaXq0ahuDQ3N7EosypVAeiq5MSS%20MSiosRKjdzE7NT4nMziEg2ggzV1FJR0lDQVkioVgF4BAJhDFVHYAAAA)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. So many new functions that it is difficult to find the right one.

Comment: I would recommend giving a onetime effort of about an hour, going through the entire list of functions. You don't need to deep dive, just understand the basic concept, or even keep it in the level of what area a function is dealing with. It will get much easier later on to identify the relevant function. P.S. Thanks for the upvote, but don't forget to close the loop by accepting the answer.

Comment: There is a wonderful feature that does not allow me to accept an answer in less than 5 minutes so I had to set up a reminder for doing it. I still remember the good old days of SO ... Your comment makes sense, thanks. Normally it is quite easy as things are common to SQL and alike but the dynamic part is quite new, I will follow your advice, thanks.